# How can I configure Quarkus to load an SPI implementation into a specific ClassLoader?

Tags: java, quarkus

I am running into an issue deploying a Quarkus App that uses an SPI implementation injected by our deployment system.

In our pom, we specify the SPI interface (which calls to ServiceLoader.load(class) in it's static initializer). When we deploy the Quarkus app, we decompose the QuarkusRunner jar, extract the Main-Class from the MANIFEST and construct a command line similar to "java -cp ... io.quarkus.bootstrap.runner.QuarkusEntryPoint". The class path includes everything in quarkus-app/app, lib/boot and lib/main plus the SPI implementation we intend to use.

When we run the app, and try to use code that invokes our SPI ServiceLoader code, we get the following error:
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: :  not a subtype.

I read this as the ClassLoader used by Quarkus (which contains the SPI-interface) and the ClassLoader that loads the SPI-Implementation, are somehow not connected (i.e., isolated from one another).

Things of interest:

- We are using Quarkus 1.13.2-Final
- I have tried to make our SPI Interface a parentFirstArtifact (it has no dependencies), with no luck.
- Looking at the code for [QuarkusEntryPoint](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/83dfbea3f828356bbb60e3a202ca4b07301d096a/independent-projects/bootstrap/runner/src/main/java/io/quarkus/bootstrap/runner/QuarkusEntryPoint.java#L17), it looks like it loads all the classes placed into quarkus/quarkus-application.dat, which is created during the maven build, into the Quarkus RunnerClassLoader, whose parent is the System ClassLoader.  My assumption was items on the classpath were added to the System ClassLoader.

Question:
At this point, I am completely lost as to what is actually happening. **How do I get my SPI-Implementation to work with Quarkus?**

Answer (score 0):

When using Quarkus's `fast-jar`, almost everything is loaded into the JVM via the `RunnerClassLoader` (the exceptions are the classloader itself, and a tiny number of supporting classes and utility libraries).

What you would consider the classpath (that is User code, code generated or transformed by Quarkus and dependencies) are indexed in the `quarkus-application.dat` file which is built at build time and cannot be modified.